# PowerShell scheduled task to run script with Excel Com Object

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

Here is some strange behavior, I've got a PowerShell script that converts an XLSX file into a CSV file.  This script runs in the console without issue.

Trying to schedule the task/script results in a CSV file with no data (0 Bytes).

In my searching, I found [this TechNet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/aede572b-4c1f-4729-bc9d-899fed5fad02/run-powershell-script-as-scheduled-task-that-uses-excel-com-object) that proved helpful.

Essentially the scheduled task containing the Powershell script that uses the Excel ComObject fails because You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows).  Once this was done, the task when run manually works as expected.  It also works when a trigger is set and the user is logged off.

**Is this type of behavior concerning the Excel ComObject documented anywhere at all?  I spent 3 hours trying to get this to work.**

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

(64Bit)

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK There are no official documentation from MS about this issue/limitation. It should be reported as a bug (contact Microsoft Support).

The requirement of a desktop folder (which SYSTEM doesn't have by default) shouldn't be necessary for excel to run and at least it should have created the folder if missing.

Comment: What's worse, that TechNet thread is from 2010.  Would this be a bug from Windows, Excel or PowerShell?

Comment: The problem is with the `Excel.Application` ComObject (or Excel application itself). The problem is documented with vbscript sample too.

Comment: I can't log a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/ so I'm not sure what next step to take.

Comment: I think you have to call Microsoft support when it comes to Office bugs. If they can reproduce it they'll make a bug report.

Comment: I'll look into that option, for now I have [posted the problem here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/schedule-windows-powershell-script-that-uses-excel/40fd5797-4504-4a3e-bfb5-9c6b62243707?tm=1457225289161)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Microsoft supports what you are attempting to do. According to this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757), Microsoft states:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

The documentation appears to be for Office 2003, but I'm not sure if they have changed there stance since then as I haven't found other documentation stating support. As recently as 2009, [this MVP](http://blogs.msmvps.com/siva/2009/03/22/server-side-automation-of-ms-office-applications/) reiterates that it isn't supported. The recommendations appear to be to use [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for non-interactive automation, or another third party library for working with the file format directly.

Comment: Now things are starting to make sense, this is what I term current behavior governed by past problems.  In the Technology world, these problems might have been identified and resolved with updated code/technology or understanding.  The suggested route, as pointed out, is to  use OpenXML and `System.IO.Package.IO` namespace in the Microsoft .NET 3.x Framework to edit Office files.  Trouble is, I've got to learn that!

Comment: Yep, I ran into a similar issue. There is a [PSExcel Module](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) that leverages [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). You could use either of those to lessen the learning burden.